# Proxy website Centos

Tags: apache-2.2, iptables, proxy, httpd

everybody would like some help from you

I wonder what I can do about it, I would like to redirect an ip from my dedicated server for a website as well?

actually would like to do something similar cloudflare

that conceals the ip plus what happens to me is the following I have a server with very good hardware too perfect, has a very strong network however suffers greatly DDOS and the server has no protection from high scale

then I would use another server as an important filter mean that another server is outside the other dedicated network

the only solution that I see in me so far would

use redirection ip with iptables.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d my_serverip -j DNAT --to-destinatio my_websiteIP
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s my_websiteIP -j SNAT --to-source my_serverIP
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

But I need my site has a dedicated ip to make the transparent redirection, anyone know what an alternative?

thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you want a reverse proxy. Nginx?

Comment: A caching reverse proxy would also take some of the load off the web server. Most web servers can act as a reverse proxy and there are also dedicated programs like varnish.

Comment: This design will not protect you from DDoS attacks. It only means that the attack will take down the proxy server, and your web site is still down anyway.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thanks for the attention, Yes I understand what you mean, only that my proxy server it has a physical firewall has DDoS protection to 500gbps / sec has protection from attack by Layer7 own datacenter, physical comprises Cisco firewall?

Comment: Can't you mount your website public IP on the rig doing NAT directly ?